# AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'as_view' in django

Tags: python, django

i already import and install djangorestframework in my project and import it to my settings, how do i call or import my serializers to my urls.py, i am getting this error **AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'as_view'**

this is my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import register

class registerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = register
        field = ('username', 'password', 'email')
```

this is my urls.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', serializers.as_view(), name='serializers')
]
```

[image]

this is my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'registrationApp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: In your case, you connected the serializer class to the URLs, and you should not be. Views are supposed to be connected with URLs patterns. Views are usually we write in `views.py` and import those classes (or functions) in `urls.py` and wire-up with URL patterns.

Comment: Moreover, you will find examples in the official doc. For a quick start, follow this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```py
from .serializers import *
# PARA el uso del API (al final)
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import *
class RegisterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = register.objects.all()
    serializer_class = registerSerializer
```

urls.py

```py
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('register', RegisterViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls), name='api-rest'),
]
```

[documentation rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/)